# Node : Connecting remote database to node server

Tags: node.js

I have node server on which i used mysql module as shown below

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
});
db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log('Errors', err)
    console.log('connenected');
})
```

when i replace ip address of remote database or ip address of my local machine on which xammp is running instead of `localhost` it fails somehow i tried to find out solution some says i need to use port in connection but it fails. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step1: Allow database to connect remote IP by given this SQL.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'ipaddressofyourpc' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Step2: Flush the PRIVILEGES

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step3:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host:'ipaddressofremotedb',
    user:'usernameofdb',
    password:'password',
    database:'dbname',
    port: 3306,
    debug: false,
    multipleStatements: true
});
```